# Why was vasuki used in Samudra Manthan great ocean Churning

Tags: samudra-manthan, naga

Why did trimurti use Vasuki Naga instead of Ananta AdiShesha of Shriman Narayana, for [Samudra Manthan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samudra_manthan)?.

Comment: I think Garuda (from Vishnu's side) and Vasuki (from Shiva's side) helped Churning of ocean. There's a story that Garuda helped in getting prerequisites for churning of ocean. But however, Garuda couldn't lift Vasuki and this was Vishnu's plan to reduce ego of Garuda. Then Shiva stretches his hand and Vasuki coils around Shiva's hand.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Okay but what about AdiShesha? and I don't know about the story of Garuda in ego. Is it because he defeated Vasuki earlier somewhere? Also I am looking for the qualification for Samudra Manthana like what qualities are possessed by Vasuki which AdiShesha doesn't have. IMO Adi Shesha is anant Infinite avatar of Shriman Narayana so he might not have bad qualities or weakness.

Comment: I think Adisesha and Ananta have slight differences. Lord Vishnu sleeps on Ananta. It always stays with Lord Vishnu, also His own expansion. **I think** Adisesha lives in Patalaloka. I'm myself not clear. See this question.  [Where does Adisesha live? In Patala loka or in Vaikuntha or underneath the earth holding it?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8899/3500)

Comment: @TheDestroyer Since Adi Shesha is avatar of Shriman Narayana he can be present in more than one loka simultaneously.

Comment: Well, that doesn't work like that. Adisesha is not Complete Vishnu. Lakshmana was short tempered and Balarama did fall into Maya of Duryodana (Kali). I think in every Manvanatara, Adisesha will born.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I disagree, Lakshmana was short tempered because he didn't want a single scratch on Rama. Balrama was incarnation of Shriman Narayana and Ananta mixed so it was his past time, its not like that he was decieved by Duryodhana

Comment: @Pandya Isn't it opinion based..?...why Vishnu supported mountain instead of Shiva or why Shiva drunk poison instead of Vishnu or why that mountain/Naga was used instead of that and so on... aren't they all opinion based Qs?